# Is it correct to say "please dribble water into the spoon" or "please dribble water onto the spoon"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[image]

The bowl of a spoon is bowed down to hold water or food.

Is it correct to say "**please dribble water into the spoon**" or "**please dribble water onto the spoon**"?

It seems native speakers say "**onto the spoon**". Why is that?

Imagine the spoon is like a tiny pool and we say "**in the pool**"

Comment: Native speakers rarely need to say, "please dribble water onto the spoon." I never have. When are you hoping to say it? What is the occasion?

Comment: I can't ever imagine saying that.  Why would you need to fill a spoon with water very slowly, in a context that you need to tell somebody else to do this and it isn't obvious.

Comment: @James K: Ha! Great minds!

Comment: That is **into** the spoon. If the spoon is the other way up, I would say **onto**.

Comment: @JamesK, say you want to pour some cough syrup onto or into it

Comment: If I wanted to pour some cough syrup into it, I would just say that. :)